# Enumerating over child entities using relationship on parent NSManagedObject VS using NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Lets say I have an instance of some NSManagedObject subclass which has 1-to-many relationship property. Performance wise, how does something like

```
for (id item in parent.children) {
   // do something with an item
}
```

compare to using a new NSFetchRequest to fetch an array of those children and enumerate over that array instead? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you will be iterating over all of your NSManagedObject's relation
your original NSFetchRequest should prefetch those relationship using : `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:`.
In this case you already paid the cost in your original fetch (and it was probably lower then).

If you don't prefetch when you are accessing each `object.relation` you will have to go to core data to have that relation populated. It's probably better than a new Fetch request.
But if you really want to do a new Fetch request, don't create one from scratch every time use the same one. And use a predicate with `predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:` to not create one from scratch every time. Creating new predicate from scratch are expensive.